# cannot be resolved to a type air hockey applet

Tags: eclipse, air

Hey I am a complete Java noob and I have been following an online tutorial teaching me to create Java apps I have used the template they game me for an air hockey applet exactly but I get "can not be resolved to a type" error for my puck and each team.  A piece of the code that appears to be the root source of the errors is as follows:

```
private Puck puck;
private Team humanTeam;
private Team compTeam;
```

Do you guys have any solutions / tips for me or have I just messed this one up completely?  I have googled it before hand and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Make sure you have declared the classes**, e.g.

```
package airhockey;

/**
 * Sample Team.java file
 */
public class Team {
    // class definition
}
```

**(2) and if you have, that they are visible where you are creating a reference**, e.g

```
import airhockey.Team;

private Team humanTeam;
```

if Team is in a package called `airhockey`, as above.

- [Java packages<sup>JLS</sup>](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html)